# Am I assigning the correct IP addresses for the routers? If not then how?

Tags: networking, routes, network-programming, router

I'm struggling to understand how to assign the ip addresses to the routers using Cisco Packet Tracer. Here's what I've done so far: https://imgur.com/a/rJYXXEv Also, This is what my homework is asking verbatim:

Build the following network;

1) 2 Routers (2811; make sure the routers have serial ports)

2) 2 Switches (2960)

3) 2 End Devices

4) Develop the router to router IP address as the 3rd subnet

Network address:  192.168.100.0/24

Divide the network into 2 equal networks (hint:  CIDR 25)

On Leg A IP address is 1st half of divided network

On Leg B IP address is 2nd half of divided network

create OSPF route from Leg A to Leg B.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that because the assignment says "make sure the routers have serial ports" you need to create a computer and connect over the serial port. Be sure to use the serial wire to connect.

Open the computer and there should be a terminal. I don't remember if you have to click anything after opening the computer but it should be obvious.

then configure routers as shown here. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/800M/software/800MSCG/routconf.html
I also highly recommend the "CCNA Routeing and Switching portable command guide" [https://www.amazon.com/Routing-Switching-Portable-Command-100-105/dp/1587205882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1587205882)

Comment: Thanks for answering. The trouble I'm having is figuring out what to assign the router IP's.

Comment: This isn't what your question asks. Please review your question